# Q: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot', etc

Tags: python, matplotlib

there~

I tried to find the root cause of this issue on my computer here and there, however, I didn't get the right way to fix it. Could you help me?

The following is my situation.

OS : Windows7 
Python : Installed by Anaconda3 full package(Python3.5.6)

Whenever I try to import every attributes in the module, I got the error messeges.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
```

There was no error messege if I just imported 'matplotlib' as above.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-52-a0d2faabd9e9>", line 1, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'
```

But, when I imported 'matplotlib.pyplot', the messege was as above. It was very weird. 
The same situation goes on importing 'pandas'.

```
import pandas as pd
```

There was also no error messege. However, when I imported 'pandas.read_csv', I got the same error messege.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("baby-names.csv")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6e6b54911d31> in <module>
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.read_csv("baby-names.csv")

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

I can't understand my situation.

**Check 1) No similar file names.**

There are no similar file name in my working directory, such as matplotlib, pandas, python files.

**Check 2) sys.path**

I'm using Spyder(Python 3.6 in Anaconda3) as an interpreter.

```
import sys
sys.path

Out[35]: 
['',
'd:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\spyder',
'd:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip',
'd:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
'd:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib',
'd:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3',
'd:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
'd:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
'd:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'd:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
'd:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
'C:\\Users\\jungkim\\.ipython']
```

**Check 3) The other interpreters**

I reconfirmed the same error in the other interpreters, such as Jupyter notebook, just command line. it was ok to import 'matplotlib' itself.

```
D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'

>>> import matplotlib as mpl

>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_csv("baby-names.csv")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

**Check 4) The package versions**

```
D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts>pip list
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- ---------
....
matplotlib                         2.2.2
....
pandas                             0.23.0
....
```

**Check 5) Modules path**

There seems to be nothing special.

```
import matplotlib as mpl    
mpl.__path__                        

Out[37]: _NamespacePath(['d:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib'])

import pandas as pd     
pd.__path__        

Out[39]: _NamespacePath(['d:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas'])
```

1. Is there anyone to suffer from the same situation?
2. Is there the way to look into the attribute lists in each module(such as Pandas, Numpy, Matplotlib, etc.)?

Comment: try renaming your csv name to baby_names.csv and then use pd.read_csv()

Comment: Try printing `pd.__dict__.keys()`. In the list, there should be `read_csv`

Comment: @Sayali Sonawane  : I appreciate your comment, Changed baby_names.csv to babynames.csv, then used pd.read_csv(), however the same error poped up. T.T

Comment: @Hoenie : Thanks, I followed your comment, In the list, there was no read_csv !  What should I do?
import pandas as pd   pd.__dict__.keys()
dict_keys(['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__path__'])

Comment: It is just a check to see if Pandas loads correctly, which it doesn’t in your case. Are you really sure you have no conflicting file names? Can you replicate this problem in a new empty working directory?

Comment: @Hoenie : Thanks actually, Your comment gave me a hint to be able to get out of the Hell, Wow!, I thought there must be something wrong with the Python path, but I couldn't get the reason. When I typed 'where python' in Window command line, the Windows said the only one python executable file in the Drive D:, However, I tried to search the Python files with 'Everything' file searching program, there were more than 5 folders related with the previous Python versions. So I removed all the folders, uninstalled Anaconda3, re-start the system and reinstalled Anaconda3, Finally I got out of the Hell

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all your comments. 
Anyway, I could get out of the hell when removed all kinds of folders related with the previous Python versions and uninstalled the Anaconda3, re-started the system, reinstalled the Anaconda3. wow~!, 
Everybody who gave comments to me made me inspire to do it! Thanks guys!

The following are the right Pandas dictionary key lists. I didn't get the lists before removing all kinds of files and folders related with the previous Python versions.

```
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bi
t (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__dict__.keys()
dict_keys(['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__pa
th__', '__file__', '__cached__', '__builtins__', '__docformat__', 'compat', 'np'
, '_np_version_under1p10', '_np_version_under1p11', '_np_version_under1p12', '_n
p_version_under1p13', '_np_version_under1p14', '_np_version_under1p15', '_libs',
 '_hashtable', '_lib', '_tslib', 'datetime', 'core', 'io', 'pandas', 'errors', '
util', 'tseries', 'plotting', 'factorize', 'unique', 'value_counts', 'isna', 'is
null', 'notna', 'notnull', 'Categorical', 'Grouper', 'set_eng_float_format', 'In
dex', 'CategoricalIndex', 'Int64Index', 'UInt64Index', 'RangeIndex', 'Float64Ind
ex', 'MultiIndex', 'IntervalIndex', 'TimedeltaIndex', 'DatetimeIndex', 'PeriodIn
dex', 'NaT', 'Period', 'period_range', 'pnow', 'Timedelta', 'timedelta_range', '
Timestamp', 'date_range', 'bdate_range', 'Interval', 'interval_range', 'Series',
 'DataFrame', 'Panel', 'WidePanel', 'get_dummies', 'IndexSlice', 'to_numeric', '
DateOffset', 'to_datetime', 'to_timedelta', 'datetools', 'get_option', 'set_opti
on', 'reset_option', 'describe_option', 'option_context', 'options', 'match', 'g
roupby', 'TimeGrouper', 'SparseArray', 'SparseSeries', 'SparseDataFrame', 'infer
  _freq', 'offsets', 'eval', 'Expr', 'concat', 'melt', 'lreshape', 'wide_to_long',
 'pivot', 'merge', 'merge_ordered', 'merge_asof', 'pivot_table', 'crosstab', 'cu
t', 'qcut', 'tools', 'plot_params', 'scatter_matrix', 'show_versions', 'api', 'r
ead_csv', 'read_table', 'read_fwf', 'read_clipboard', 'ExcelFile', 'ExcelWriter'
, 'read_excel', 'HDFStore', 'get_store', 'read_hdf', 'read_json', 'read_html', '
read_sql', 'read_sql_table', 'read_sql_query', 'read_sas', 'read_feather', 'read
_parquet', 'read_stata', 'read_pickle', 'to_pickle', 'read_msgpack', 'to_msgpack
', 'read_gbq', 'Term', 'test', 'testing', '_DeprecatedModule', 'json', 'parser',
 'lib', 'tslib', '_version', '__version__'])
>>>
```